# NPM package deep dependency separation

Tags: javascript, npm, package, node-modules, package.json

I'm developing an NPM package, that I would like to be shared between a couple of web apps.
This package uses some 3rd party libraries, for example, `ag-grid@14`.
The problem is, that the consuming web app has its own dependency `ag-grid@18`. 
When installing my package, it installs the `ag-grid@14` under `node_modules` of the consuming web-app, which will be overridden by its own `ag-grid@18` dependency.

Is there a way to specify my package to be installed with its own `ag-grid` and use it? (not from the main `node_modules` but from its own?)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried pinning the version in `package.json`? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is what happens when the consuming web app installs ag-grid@18, it will override the installation of ag-grid@14 that was installed by the npm package (as its dependency)